# Embed strings in html in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make rails' flash messages style with bootstrap 3.

In this piece of code,

```
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
    <% end %>
```

`<%=key>` puts the key into the class tag like you'd expect. But when I change the middle line to this

```
<div class="<%= flash_class(key) %>"><%= value %></div>
```

`<%= flash_class(key)%>` doesn't embed anything.

`flash_class()` is in `application_helper.rb` which is automatically included in views (right?) and it returns a string. I think it's probably something stupid I'm missing, why does this not work?

edit- here's the implementation of flash_class

```
   def flash_class(level)
        case level
            when :notice then "alert alert-info"
            when :success then "alert alert-success"
            when :error then "alert alert-error"
            when :alert then "alert alert-error"
        end
    end
```

Comment: what is your implementation of the `flash_class` method?

Comment: Can you add `else "alert not recognized"` and `case level.to_sym`? The else will return a default string if none is found, and the `.to_sym` will make sure the key is a symbol

Comment: Sounds a lot like a naming mismatch. Try adding a default case to flash_class just saying `"#{level} not found"`.

Comment: First thing i always do in this sort of situation is to log the `flash_class` method, what is passed through for "level".  You might find it's a string rather than a symbol.

Comment: That was exactly what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a problem comparing string with symbols:

```
def flash_class(level)
  case level.to_sym
```

Should solve your problem

Comment: This is basically what I'm doing, only I'm formatting the class name to work with bootstrap. The bootstrap alert names and rails' flash keys aren't the same.

Comment: @NathanTempelman I updated my answer with an `else` statement in the case + `.to_sym` on `level` variable

Comment: I tried your else statement, and it put out "key not recognized". then I replaced it with level, and it came back as "notice". Then I tried your to_sym, and now it works. I guess you can't compare strings and symbols? And also I guess keys are always symbols?

Comment: Update your answer to include the symbol comparing shenannigan, and I'll accept it. Thanks for the help

Comment: No, keys can either be string or symbol. A HashWithIndifferentAccess is the same as a Hash except that you can access a value with either the key as a string or as a symbol. Your `flash` variable is a simple Hash, not HashWithIndifferentAccess -- @NathanTempelman my answer already uses a `.to_sym` on the key, what do you want me to change?

Comment: I guess shorten it? The only bit of my code that didn't work was the to_sym bit, and that detail kind of gets lost in your answer. Just mention I'm an idiot and was comparing strings and symbols (PS why doesn't that just work?)

Comment: You can do `flash.with_indifferent_access` to be able to do either `flash[:error]` AND `flash['error']`

Comment: Won't I be able to do that anyway? Because it's converted to a symbol either way right?